# How to remove the brackets from this string?

Tags: javascript

I'm messing around with this open API that I found. I returns a random Ron Swanson quote each time you GET from it.

The problem is that each the response.data comes out like this:

> [ "Fish, for sport only, not for meat. Fish meat is practically a vegetable." ]

with brackets surrounding the text - which I don't want. Ive tried using slice() to get rid of the brackets but it doesn't seem to work.

What very simple thing am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just did a quick google search to find the API you are using -- https://github.com/jamesseanwright/ron-swanson-quotes is what it looks like.

Instead of returning a string with brackets, this API returns an array with a single value! So no need to perform any string manipulation, just access `response.data[0]` to get the string that you want.

Edit: Slice would have been the correct way to remove the brackets if they were a part of the response string. Good instinct!

Answer (score 3):

It's an array. Use subscripting notation to get the first element:

```
var response = [ "Fish, etc." ];
var text = response[0]; // "Fish, etc." (without the brackets)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use .split() if you're dealing with strings

```
var myVar = '["Uvuvwevwevwe Onyetenyevwe Ugwemubwem Osas"]';
myVar2 = myVar.split("[")[1];
myVar3 = myVar2.split("]")[0];
```

The final variable would hold "Uvuvwevwevwe Onyetenyevwe Ugwemubwem Osas".

The [] on the split method denotes the index of the divided string where "aXb" when split using split("X"), a is index 0, b is index 1.

Comment: I think "Osas" should be "Ossas"?